# ModelState showing validationstate as invalid for a field that is not required

Tags: .net, validation, model, razor-pages, model-binding

I am using Razor Pages. I have two fields that in a model that are NOT required:

```
`    public class OrderModel : EntityModel, IValidatableObject
    {        
        public string UserId { get; set; } 
        public int PortfolioId { get; set; }
        public int StockId { get; set; }
        public int StockHoldingId { get; set; }
        public string StockSymbol { get; set; } 

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Shares Traded")]
        public int QuantityTraded { get; set; }`
```

The two fields are UserId and StockSymbol. I have the following portion of a form, with the UserId and StockSymbol being nonexistent so null or empty, which I am purposely doing:

```
`        <div>
            Quantity: <input type="number" min="0" asp-for="@Model.Order.QuantityTraded" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Stock.Id" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Stock.Symbol" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Stock.Price" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Stock.StockName" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Stock.Description" />
            <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="Buy" asp-page-handler="Buy" />
            <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="Sell" asp-page-handler="Sell" />
        </div>`
```

When I submit the form, I am having an invalid ModelState as shown below:

[image]

It is showing "UserId field is required" and "StockSymbol field is required". What else can be causing this requirement, when the [Required] attribute is clearly not there for them?

As requested, Here is the Validate method:

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    if (QuantityTraded < 1)
    {
        yield return new ValidationResult(
            $"Quantity must be greater than 0.",
            new[] { nameof(QuantityTraded) });
    }
}
```

Comment: show us the `IValidatableObject.Validate(ValidationContext)` implementation method on `OrderModel`.  `EntityModel` may be implementing it if `OrderModel` isn't explicitly doing so. 
Either way, that is really the answer to 'What else can be causing this requirement'.

Comment: also, the type you are showing us isn't the type used for 'Stock' property, right? i.e, if your model is `OrderEntity` then it has a property `Stock` -- what does that type (`@Model.Stock`) define as `Required`? which again, could be either `DataAnnotation.RequiredAttribute` or `IValidatableObject.Validate`

Comment: @Brett Caswell I am using Razor Pages, and my page is submitting two separate models: Stock and Order

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this. may be following things will help you.
Its applicable for updated .NET core 5 > versions.

```
public class OrderModel
{        
    public string? UserId { get; set; }
    public string? StockSymbol { get; set; }
}
```

Or remove following tag in .csproj file

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

Comment: Aren't strings nullable by definition?

Comment: NOPE, make <Nullable>disable</Nullable> or remove tags

Comment: interesting... did this actually address this ModelState issue @HoboJeff? if that's the case, it would seem non-nullable reference type -- which is supposed to be a compile time static analysis feature -- does have runtime checking.  That seems contray to what the docs state https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types#nullable-references-and-static-analysis

Comment: I wonder if you did a release build (or turned off runtime compilation with razor pages.) whether this ModelState invalidation issue would occur. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#enable-runtime-compilation-conditionally

Comment: @Brett Caswell It sure did address the issue! It worked. Pandurang is awesome. So are you, Brett! Stackoverflow is the greatest !